# how to find WSDL URL from Request XML for given soap web service?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have to find out WSDL URL to get the definition of the methods exist the in webservice, so that I can consume data.

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:met="http://schemas.esb.ams.com/meterusagesource">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<met:processMeterUsage>
<MeterUsageReqList>
<userId>JONBREZON</userId>
<userType>THRD</userType>
<reportTypeArray>

<reportFormat>CSV</reportFormat>
<ESIIDArray>
<!--1 or more repetitions:-->
<ESIID>1008901022900060000000</ESIID>
</ESIIDArray>
</MeterUsageReqList>
</met:processMeterUsage>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Do you mean to find endpoint of the request? or To find all the operation of service?

Comment: @Rao end point of the request

Comment: Where do you need to access the endpoint of the request? In a groovy script?

Comment: can you try the answer and see if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have post the request from the web services

The WSDL has a different format and you cannot get it from the request.

Maybe you have to look for the URL throw other way not by the code you have shared here.

Maybe this links will be useful for you

WSDL definition: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_wsdl.asp

Soap request definition: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the test case has two test steps, namely

- step1, soap request test step
- step2, groovy script test step; and here you need to access the endpoint of step1.

Here is the *Groovy Script*:

```
//Getting the step1 using its index 0, change if need to suite your environment  
​def step = context.testCase.getTestStepAt(0)
//Get the endpoint of step1
def endPoint = step.getPropertyValue('Endpoint')​
//log the value
log.info "End point of step1 is ${endPoint}"
```